# Adding Item to Database in Laravel with AJAX and then showing Item

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

After hours of Googling, I can't seem to find an answer to this seemingly simple problem. I can't add data to a database and show that data without refreshing the page. My goal is to be able to create an object from a form to upload to a database, and then show all the items in database (without the page refreshing). I have tried to get AJAX working many times, but I can't seem to do that. The application works by adding stars to students, so basically I would want to be able to update a students star count without reloading the page. But right now I can't even `console.log` the submitted form data. My Controller code is like so:

```
    public function addStar(){

    $id = Input::get('id');
    $user_id = Input::get('user_id');

    if(Auth::user()->id == $user_id){

        Student::addStar($id);

    }

    return Redirect::back();

}
```

And my form:

```
             {{Form::open(array('action'=>'HomeController@addStar','id'=>'addStar','method'=>'post'))}}
        {{ Form::hidden('id', $student->id, array('id'=>'id_value')) }}
        {{ Form::hidden('user_id', $student->user_id, array('id'=>'user_id_value'))}}
        {{ Form::submit('+')}}
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

And my extremely poor attempts at AJAX:

```
$('#addStar').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/addstar',
        data: $('#addStar').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {

            console.log(data);
        },

    });
    return false;
});
```

The code works fine if I settle for allowing page reloads, but I don't want that. So essentially, my question is, how do I add data to a database and show it without the page reloading? Thanks so much!

Comment: Why are you redirecting?

Comment: I wanted to reload the same view after the form data was submitted-essentially i wanted to reload the view where the form exists.

Comment: Well, you should return a value using `Response::json()`. If you don't have the template on the client-side, render the view on the server, return the view and replace the old view with the new one using jQuery `replaceWith` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller is doing a redirect after the logic, ajax won't be able to do anything with the response. A one take would be, after adding a start returning the new star rating.

```
public function addStar(){

    $id      = Input::get('id');
    $user_id = Input::get('user_id');

    if(Auth::user()->id == $user_id){

        Student::addStar($id);

    }

    $star_count = //get new star count;

    return Response::json(['star_count' => $star_count]);
}
```

Since controller now returns a json response, the `success` callback on $.ajax can grab it and do something (update the star count).

Comment: So there is no way to reload a view? I wish to update the star count, then have the page update without refreshing. Or is there a way to "inject" this JSON into my current view?

Comment: @codeforfood If you only want to update the count value, reloading the whole view is overkill, in that case using Ajax doesn't make a lot of sense. As you are using jQuery you can easily traverse the DOM and update the view using the returned JSON. If the updated value fundamentally affects the old data, you can re-render the view either on the server or client-side and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

@codeforfood,

If you want to grab the response and show it immediately in the page without a reload then you may go with returning a JSON reponse and then handle that response at the client side Javascript for Success or Failure conditions.

Can try something like this if you want:
In the controller addStar() method response:

```
$data = ['star_count' => 'COUNT OF STARS'];
return json_encode($data);
```

In the View for that specific Star Div:

```
    <script>
        $('#stardiv).on('submit', function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "{{URL::to('xxxxx')}}",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (data) {
Handle the success condition here, you can access the response data through data['star_count']
                },
                error: function (data) {
Handle the error condition here, may be show an alert of failure
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

After all this is just one approach, you may try different one which ever suits your need.